# Como evitar demasiados try/except?

Tags: python, design-pattern

Possuo o código abaixo que joga valores dentro de chaves em um dicionário. Porém, preciso de vários `try` / `except` para que o código funcione perfeitamente, visto que, na falta de um dos campos, o código vai retornar uma ***KeyError Exception*** e o código vai quebrar.

Há alguma maneira mais otimizada e/ou mais simples de resolver o problema?

Código:

```
issue_fmt = {}
issue_fmt['assignee'] = {}
issue_fmt['assignee']['display_name'] = ''
issue_fmt['reporter'] = {}
issue_fmt['reporter']['display_name'] = ''
issue_fmt['key'] = ''
issue_fmt['project'] = {}
issue_fmt['project']['name'] = ''

def format_doc(issue):

    try:
        issue_fmt['assignee']['display_name'] = issue['assignee']['display_name']
    except:
        issue_fmt['assignee']['display_name'] = ''
    try:
        issue_fmt['reporter']['display_name'] = issue['reporter']['display_name']
    except:
        issue_fmt['reporter']['display_name'] = ''
    try:
        issue_fmt['key'] = issue['key']
    except:
        issue_fmt['key'] = ''
    try:
        issue_fmt['description'] = issue['description']
    except:
        issue_fmt['description'] = ''
    try:
        issue_fmt['project']['name'] = issue['project']['name']
    except:
        issue_fmt['project']['name'] = '' 

    return dict(issue_fmt)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O dicionário possui um método `get` que pode receber como segundo parâmetro um valor que será retornado quando a chave buscada não existir. Então ao invés de fazer:

```
try:
    issue_fmt['assignee']['display_name'] = issue['assignee']['display_name']
except:
    issue_fmt['assignee']['display_name'] = ''
```

Basta você fazer

```
issue_fmt['assignee']['display_name'] = issue['assignee'].get('display_name', '')
```

Assim, ficaria:

```
def format_doc(issue):
    issue_fmt['assignee']['display_name'] = issue['assignee'].get('display_name', '')
    issue_fmt['reporter']['display_name'] = issue['reporter'].get('display_name')
    issue_fmt['key'] = issue.get('key', '')
    issue_fmt['description'] = issue.get('description', '')
    issue_fmt['project']['name'] = issue['project'].get('name', '')

    return dict(issue_fmt)
```

Mas outros pontos devem ser considerados:

1. Por que `issue_fmt` é definido fora da função e não dentro dela?
2. Se `issue_fmt` já é um dicionário, por que retornar `dict(issue_fmt)`?

Comment: Perfeito, o método get resolveu o meu problema. Obrigado! O issue_fmt está definido fora apenas pra simplificar o exemplo. Na verdade, ele é lido de um outro arquivo. Sobre o retorno, realmente é uma redundância desnecessária, acabei de corrigir.